# Excel .csv lines don't contain quotations in Excel, but other editors add them. MySQL doesn't like this

Tags: mysql, excel, quotations

I am using DbVisualizer 23.1 to edit MySQL queries. I am learning through the various sources that exist, and I've run into a frustrating problem. I created two .csv files in Excel 365 with the tables you can see here: https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_with_expressions

Movies and Boxoffice only have the A column populated with ',' as the expected delimiter. I don't have quotations around the lines, but I do have quotations around "Monsters, Inc." [that's not the compiling error].

When I open the .csv in Notepad or MySQL there are quotations around each line. It's frustrating but that's fine because we use `ENCLOSED BY '"'` in our INFILE block, right? When I try to run the following:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Boxoffice.csv'
INTO TABLE Boxoffice
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(Movie_id, Rating, Domestic_sales, International_sales);
```

I receive the error:

> [Code: 1366, SQL State: HY000]  Incorrect integer value:
> '"5,8.2,380843261,555900000" "14,7.4,268492764,475066843"
> "8,8,206445654,417277164" "12,6.4,191452396,368400000" "3,7.9,24585'
> for column 'Movie_id' at row 1

It doesn't appear to like the quotations that appear in the Excel-created csv. I can get the table populated if I include `SET Id = CAST(REPLACE(@Movie_id, '"', '') AS UNSIGNED)` but am I going to have to do this every time? All of the literature I read tells me that `ENCLOSED BY '"'` or `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` should make the quotations a moot point. What am I missing?

Edit: Adding the Notepad version of the Boxoffice.csv (remember the Excel version doesn't have the quotations that I discussed above):

```
"5,8.2,380843261,555900000"
"14,7.4,268492764,475066843"
"8,8,206445654,417277164"
"12,6.4,191452396,368400000"
"3,7.9,245852179,239163000"
"6,8,261441092,370001000"
"9,8.5,223808164,297503696"
"11,8.4,415004880,648167031"
"1,8.3,191796233,170162503"
"7,7.2,244082982,217900167"
"10,8.3,293004164,438338580"
"4,8.1,289916256,272900000"
"2,7.2,162798565,200600000"
"13,7.2,237283207,301700000"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add the following line to your instructions:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '"\n' STARTING BY '"'
```

that should do the trick saying to mysql that the double quotes are just wrapping an entire new line.

[Source][1]

So your code should become:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Boxoffice.csv'
INTO TABLE Boxoffice
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '"\n' STARTING BY '"'
(Movie_id, Rating, Domestic_sales, International_sales);
```

See that this is untested and may require some more tweaks to adjust to your real situation
[1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thank you. I tried `LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Boxoffice.csv'
INTO TABLE Boxoffice
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '"\n' STARTING BY '"'
(Movie_id, Rating, Domestic_sales, International_sales);`

And I received a data truncation error: `[Code: 1265, SQL State: 01000]  Data truncated for column 'International_sales' at row 1`

I don't understand as I have the data type as BIGINT. So your solution may work but I'm still unable to compile.

Comment: Movie_id int NO PRI (null) 
Rating float YES  (null) 
Domestic_sales int YES  (null) 
International_sales bigint YES  (null)

Comment: as you can see I didn't put the `enclosed by '"'` part in my code. you don't have each field wrapped in quotes. remove that part and you should be doing fine

Comment: So I went ahead and took out that line `enclosed by '"'` and changed the data type issue with integers to varchar(20). I was able to compile, but I received the following output [link]https://imgur.com/a/3WSLWNQ